# Defining classes at runtime

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of classes (or class names) and returns a class that has all given classes as superclasses. This should return the same class again when given the same list twice, so I am using a hash table for memoization.
I can not use defclass for that purpose as it doesn't evaluate it's DIRECT-SUPERCLASSES parameter. I didn't find any corresponding function in the HyperSpec.
Is there any way I can do this portably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create the DEFCLASS form and evaluate it with EVAL.

You can also use the CLOS function ENSURE-CLASS.

Comment: Where can I find ENSURE-CLASS?

Comment: Ah, you mean the mop function ensure-class. It's not in the standard.

Comment: @Thomas Bartscher: most CL implementations have it.

Comment: I guess that it's not portable, but I found it in closer-mop, which is distributed through quicklisp, so I am using that.